# Compiler error Exit status 1

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

```
g++ -Wall -o "3bV2" "3bV2.cpp" (in directory: /home/dylan/Desktop/3b/Done)
/tmp/ccA8cFDY.o: In function `main':
3bV2.cpp:(.text+0x9ca): undefined reference to `struct_cmp_by_product(void const*, void const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

I get this error when compiling. NOTE: It worked fine until I externalized my function.

MAIN.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //reqd for strncat
#include <stdlib.h> // reqd for exit()
#include "./TAXRATES.h"
#include "./EmployeeRecord.h"
#define HEADERLINE1 "       Employee's             Pay      RegHours    Gross    Fed      SSI     Net\n"
#define HEADERLINE2 "       Name                   Rate     OvtHours    Worked   State    Defr\n"
#define HEADERLINE3 "       *******************    *****    ********    *******  ******   ******  ******\n"
#define REPLNEFORMT1 "       %-22s%6.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Main Header Line 1 (Thank you Dixon)
#define REPLNEFORMT2 "       %40.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n\n"//Main Header Line 2 (Thank you Dixon)
#define REPLNEFORMT3 "       %-21s%7.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Totals Line 1
#define MAX_SIZE 5

void EmptyFileError(void);//3.01
void InitializeAccumulators(float *totreg, float *totovt,float *totpayrate, float                           
                            *totgross, float *totfed, float *totstate, float *totssi, float                     
                            *totdefr, float *totnet); //3.02
void PrintReportHeadings(FILE * reportfile); //3.03
void NumberOfEmployees(int *NumEmployees); //3.04
void InputEmployeeData(char Ln[],char Fn[], float *Hours,float *Payrate, float               
                        *defr, float *ovt); // 3.05
float CalculateGross(float Hours,float Payrate);//3.06
void computeTaxes(float g,float d,float * fed,float *state,float *ssi); //3.07
void PrintUserData(float p,float Hours,float g,float fed,float ssi,float n,char str1[30],float ovt, 
                    float state,float d, FILE *reportfile);//3.09
void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, float p, float Hours, float *totreg,
                    float g, float *totgross, float fed, float *totfed, float ssi,                  
                    float *totssi, float n, float *totnet,
                    float *totovt,float  ovt, float state, float *totstate, float                   
                    defr, float *totdefr);//3.10
void CalcAverage(float totpayrate, float *avgtotpayrate,float totreg, float          
                *avgtotreg,float totgross, float *avgtotgross, float *avgtotfed, float totfed,
                float *avgtotssi, float totssi, float *avgtotnet, float totnet,
                float *avgtotovt, float totovt, float *avgtotstate, float totstate,
                float *avgtotdefr, float totdefr);//3.11
void PrintSummaryReport(float totpayrate, float totreg, float totgross,float totfed,
                        float totssi, float totnet, float totovt,float totstate,float                       
                        totdefr,float avgtotpayrate,float avgtotreg,float avgtotgross,float                 
                        avgtotfed, float avgtotssi,float avgtotnet,float avgtotovt,float                
                        avgtotstate,float avgtotdefr, FILE *reportfile);//3.12
void CalculateOT(float *Hours, float *ovt);//*3..11
void computeTaxes(float g,float d,float * fed,float *state,float *ssi); //3.07
float cFed(float g,float d); // 3.8.1
float cState(float ft); // 3.8.2
float cSSI(float g,float d); // 3.8.3
extern int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b);
void computeTaxes(float g,float d,float * ft,float *st,float *ssit)
{ // 3.5
   *ft = cFed(g,d); //  vs ft = cFed(g,d)
   *st = cState(*ft); // call 3.5.2
   *ssit = cSSI(g,d); // call 3.5.3
}   
float cFed(float g,float d) // 3.5.1
{
      return (g-d) * FEDTAXRATE;
}      
float cState(float ft) // 3.5.2
{
      return ft * STATETAXRATE;
}   
float cSSI(float g,float d) // 3.5.3
{
      return (g-d) * SSITAXRATE;
}

int main(void)
{
    EmployeeRecord MyAssociate[MAX_SIZE];
    float totpayrate, totreg, totovt, totgross, totfed, totstate, totssi,                   
            totdefr,totnet,avgtotpayrate,avgtotreg, avgtotgross,avgtotfed,
            avgtotssi, avgtotnet, avgtotovt, avgtotstate, avgtotdefr,                           
            ovt;
    // step 1: declare a report "file" variable
    FILE * reportfile;
    reportfile = fopen("./report.txt","wt");
    // step 2: open the "file" for "write-text" access
    if (reportfile == NULL)
    {
        EmptyFileError();
    }
    InitializeAccumulators(&totpayrate,&totreg,&totovt,&totgross,&totfed,&totstate,
                            &totssi,&totdefr,&totnet);
    PrintReportHeadings(reportfile);
    for (int EmpCounter = 0; EmpCounter < MAX_SIZE; EmpCounter++)
    {
        InputEmployeeData(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Lastname,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Firstname,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Hours,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Payrate,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Defr,&ovt);// call 3.3
        strcpy(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FullName, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Lastname);
        strcat(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FullName, ", ");
        strcat(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FullName, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Firstname);
        CalculateOT(&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Hours, &ovt);
        MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Gross =  CalculateGross(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Hours,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Payrate); // call 3.4
        computeTaxes(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Gross,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Defr,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FedTax,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].StateTax,&MyAssociate[EmpCounter].SsiTax); // call 3.5
        MyAssociate[EmpCounter].NetPay = MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Gross-MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FedTax-MyAssociate[EmpCounter].StateTax-MyAssociate[EmpCounter].SsiTax-MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Defr;
        PrintUserData(MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Payrate,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Hours,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Gross,
            MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FedTax,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].SsiTax,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].NetPay,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FullName,ovt,
            MyAssociate[EmpCounter].StateTax,MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Defr,reportfile);
        AddDetailToAccumulators(&totpayrate, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Payrate, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Hours, &totreg,
                         MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Gross, &totgross, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].FedTax, &totfed, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].SsiTax, &totssi, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].NetPay, &totnet,                        
                         &totovt, ovt, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].StateTax, &totstate, MyAssociate[EmpCounter].Defr, &totdefr);
          while(getchar() != '\n'); // flush(stdin)
    }  
    CalcAverage(totpayrate, &avgtotpayrate,totreg,&avgtotreg, totgross,                 
                &avgtotgross, &avgtotfed, totfed, &avgtotssi, totssi,&avgtotnet, totnet,            
                &avgtotovt, totovt, &avgtotstate, totstate,&avgtotdefr, totdefr);
    qsort(MyAssociate, MAX_SIZE, sizeof(struct EmployeeRecord), struct_cmp_by_product);//sort
    fclose(reportfile); // step 4: close the report file
    getchar();
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    return 0;
}
void EmptyFileError(void) //3.01
{
      printf(" Report file open failed ...\n");
      printf("   Press key to exit ...\n");
      while (getchar() != '\n'); // same as fflush(stdin)
      exit(-10); // reqs <stdlib.h>
}
void InitializeAccumulators(float *totpayrate, float *totreg,float *totovt,float                            
                            *totgross,float *totfed,float *totstate,
                            float *totssi, float *totdefr, float *totnet) //3.02
{
    *totpayrate = 0;
    *totreg = 0;
    *totovt = 0;
    *totgross = 0;
    *totfed = 0;
    *totstate = 0;
    *totssi = 0;
    *totdefr = 0;
    *totnet = 0;
}
void PrintReportHeadings(FILE * reportfile)//3.03
{
    fprintf(stdout,HEADERLINE1);
    fprintf(stdout,HEADERLINE2);
    fprintf(stdout,HEADERLINE3);
    fprintf(reportfile,HEADERLINE1);
    fprintf(reportfile,HEADERLINE2);
    fprintf(reportfile,HEADERLINE3);
}
void InputEmployeeData(char Ln[],char Fn[],
                       float Hours[],float *Payrate, float *defr, float *ovt)//3.05
{
    printf(" Enter the name ==> ");
    scanf("%s%s",Fn,Ln);
    printf(" Enter the hours and payrate ==> ");
    scanf("%f%f",Hours,Payrate);
    printf("  Enter the deferred earning amount ==> ");
    scanf("%f",defr);
}
void CalculateOT(float *Hours, float *ovt)//3.06 FLOWCHART!!!!
{
    if (*Hours > 40){
         *ovt = *Hours - 40;
         *Hours = *Hours - *ovt;
         }
    else
    {
        *ovt = 0.00;
     }
}
float CalculateGross(float Hours,float Payrate)//3.7
{
  if (Hours <= 40)
    return Hours * Payrate;
  else
    return 40* Payrate + 1.5 * Payrate * (Hours-40);
}
void PrintUserData(float p,float h,float g,float fed,float ssi,float n,char str1[30],
                 float ovt, float state,float d,FILE * reportfile)//3.09
{
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT1,str1,p,h<=40?h:40,g,fed,ssi,n);  
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT2,ovt,state,d);
        fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT1,str1,p,h<=40?h:40,g,fed,ssi,n);  
        fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT2,ovt,state,d);
}
void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, float p, float h, float *totreg,
                    float g, float *totgross, float fed, float *totfed, float ssi,                  
                    float *totssi, float n, float *totnet, float *totovt,
                    float ovt, float state, float *totstate, float defr, float *totdefr)//3.10
{   
    *totpayrate = p + *totpayrate;
    *totreg = h + *totreg;
    *totgross = g + *totgross;
    *totfed = fed + *totfed;
    *totssi = ssi + *totssi;
    *totnet = n + *totnet;
    *totovt = ovt + *totovt;
    *totstate = state + *totstate;
    *totdefr = defr + *totdefr;
}
void CalcAverage(float totpayrate, float *avgtotpayrate, float totreg, float *avgtotreg, float totgross, float *avgtotgross, float *avgtotfed, float            totfed, float *avgtotssi, float totssi,float *avgtotnet, float totnet,
            float *avgtotovt, float totovt, float *avgtotstate, float totstate, float *avgtotdefr, float totdefr)//3.11
{
    *avgtotpayrate = totpayrate / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotreg = totreg / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotgross = totgross / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotfed = totfed / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotssi = totssi / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotnet = totnet / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotovt = totovt / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotstate = totstate / MAX_SIZE;
    *avgtotdefr = totdefr / MAX_SIZE;
}
```

Qsort.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./EmployeeRecord.h"
#include <string.h> 
#define REPLNEFORMT1 "       %-22s%6.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Main Header Line 1 (Thank you Dixon)
#define REPLNEFORMT2 "       %40.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n\n"//Main Header Line 2 (Thank you Dixon)
#define MAX_SIZE 5
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b);
void print_struct_array_pre(EmployeeRecord MyAssociate[]);
void print_struct_array_post(EmployeeRecord MyAssociate[]);

void print_struct_array_pre(EmployeeRecord MyAssociate[]) 
{ 
    int i;
         printf("       ***********ARRAY BEFORE NOT BEEN SORTED YET***************\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        //printf("%s %s]\n", MyAssociate[i].Lastname, MyAssociate[i].Firstname);
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT1,MyAssociate[i].FullName,MyAssociate[i].Payrate,
            MyAssociate[i].Hours<=40?MyAssociate[i].Hours:40,MyAssociate[i].Gross,MyAssociate[i].FedTax,
            MyAssociate[i].SsiTax,MyAssociate[i].NetPay);  
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT2,MyAssociate[i].OVT,MyAssociate[i].StateTax,MyAssociate[i].Defr);
    }
} 
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct EmployeeRecord *ia = (struct EmployeeRecord *)a;
    struct EmployeeRecord *ib = (struct EmployeeRecord *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->FullName, ib->FullName);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */
}
void print_struct_array_post(EmployeeRecord MyAssociate[]) 
{ 
    int i;
         printf("       ***********ARRAY HAS BEEN SORTED VIA QUICK-SORT***************\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        //printf("%s %s]\n", MyAssociate[i].Lastname, MyAssociate[i].Firstname);
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT1,MyAssociate[i].FullName,MyAssociate[i].Payrate,
            MyAssociate[i].Hours<=40?MyAssociate[i].Hours:40,MyAssociate[i].Gross,MyAssociate[i].FedTax,
            MyAssociate[i].SsiTax,MyAssociate[i].NetPay);  
        fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT2,MyAssociate[i].OVT,MyAssociate[i].StateTax,MyAssociate[i].Defr);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by there is no function called `qsort`? It's in `stdlib.h`

Comment: `qsort()` is a very well know function that is part of the C library.  Your first assertion is that it doesn't exist and you need to re-write it or something, that assertion is false.  (see the first comment)

Comment: Why do you name your source `.cpp` and compile with `g++` while your code (and tag) is "C"?

Comment: Because it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a self contained example of what you seem to be doing.  Although it doesn't give me any compiler errors on visual studio compiled as vanilla c++.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int cmp_char(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void)
{
    char arr[13] = "cbacbacbacba";

    qsort(arr, sizeof(arr) - 1, sizeof(char), cmp_char);

    printf("arr = %s\n", arr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int cmp_char(const void *a, const void *b);

int cmp_char(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
   char *pa = (char*)a;
   char *pb = (char*)b;

   return *pa - *pb;
}
```

Note: Your example already has an extern reference in main.cpp to the function in the other file, so I don't see why you'd get the error you are getting.  Could it be you need both c++ files on the compiler command line?  (So it knows to compile and link both files together?)

Comment: I got it working. My Problem was 2 things. 1) I need to link my files in command line. 2) I was calling the print from the external function. It should work that way but it was printing empty.

Answer (score 0):

If the compare function is in a different source file than the one calling qsort(), then declare the compare function as external in the source file that calls qsort(). qsort() is declared as external in stdlib.h. so no issue there. If this is c++, you could also use std::sort() or std::stable_sort(), but you've tagged this as c?

So in main.c, add this line:

```
extern int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b);
```

Comment: Please take a quick peak at my code (I edited main post)

Comment: @GeekyDewd - ok, so did that solve the linker issue?